# AngularJS $http post to non existing url 404

Tags: angularjs, node.js

This may be one of these questions that doesn't need much explanation i just didn't found the answer elsewhere.

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and NodeJS. I did some tutorials and now i try to put something together.

In nodeJS when i do something like this:

```
app.get('/db-get-extra-bookings', function(req, res) {

    res.json({name: "hello"});

});
```

than in AngularJS i can `GET` that response and do something with that even if `/db-insert-extra-bookings` is **not an fysical page**

```
return $http
    .get(formURL)
    .then(function(response){

    // some code

    });
```

But when i want to post something from out of AngularJS to my NodeJs environment

```
return $http
    .post(formJson, JSON.stringify(bookings))
    .then(function(response){

        //some code

    });
```

NodeJS:

```
app.get('/db-insert-extra-bookings', function(req, res) {

    // do something with the request

});
```

I got a 404 error in my webbrowser console.

```
base.js:5 POST http://localhost:3000/db-insert-extra-bookings 404 (Not Found)
```

It sounds like normal behaviour, but why am i getting a `404 error` when i `POST` to a non existing page, and why am i getting the data like i want when i `GET` from a non existing page?

Do i really need to make an empty page to post to?

Comment: It should be `app.post('/db-insert-extra-bookings', function(req, res) {`

Comment: @mparnisari i did a bad copy paste. In my code it is `app.post`

Comment: *"Do i really need to make an empty page to post to?"* no. either your url is wrong or your route is incorrectly (or not) defined.

Comment: So after writing everything again i manage to find what was wrong. in my main nodeJS file i forgot to call the module.exports function and passing the app `insertExtraBookings(app);`. I know these are stupid (beginner) mistakes. To the persons who gave the -1 can you please explain why you gave this? You cannot judge and than not explain why! I think there is nothing wrong with the question itself?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a expert in NodeJS, but if you want to create a route that answer any HTTP method you should use `app.all()` instead of `app.get()`. In your code you are just creating a route for `GET` requests, that is why it works for a GET and don't work for a POST. Check out this [reference](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just to clarify, NodeJS endpoints (GET included) do not need to serve an HTML page to work. You can send any type of HTTP response, e.g. plain text, JSON, HTML, etc - with the appropriate `'Content-Type'` header.

In NodeJS routes:

```
app.post('/db-get-extra-bookings', function(req, res) {
    res.json({name: "hello"});
});
```

Now in your angular code (You don't need to `JSON.stringify`):

```
// Change localhost:9000 with your hostname
$http.post('http://localhost:9000/db-get-extra-bookings', bookings)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // console.log(data);
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // console.log(status);            
});
```

**Also**, remember to restart your NodeJS server for the changes to take effect.